# How do I validate OAuth requests?

Tags: oauth

I'm trying to use OAuth with Twitter, and I have my head wrapped around the pieces that need to be put in place to get a request token. But, it's not working. And the error message that I'm getting back isn't terribly helpful.

Luckily I found [a tester](http://term.ie/oauth/example/) but again, the error message there isn't terribly helpful. "Invalid signature." Ok, great. But since there are several steps involved (truth be told, all of which confuse the hell out of me) in generating the signature, I'm at a loss.

Is there another tool out there that might be more helpful? Maybe one where I can see what the data should be at each step (check that the request concatenation is right, check that the initial signing is right - i'm using HMAC-SHA1, check that the base 64 is right, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Run, do not walk, to [Hueniverse](http://www.hueniverse.com/hueniverse/2008/10/beginners-gui-1.html) - one of the neatest pieces of Javascript you'll see!

Comment: didn't notice this there the first time I visited that site, which came off like a total tl;dr at first glance. Glad I ran there. :)

Comment: Yes, that site does take a while to get going. Worth it in the end though. Another good test site is (of all places) myspace.com.